# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: My take on this: participation is fairly low on the site in general, and the participation in this survey reflects that. Evaluation favors well-researched, factual answers over speculation (even informed speculation). That's good, but it is somewhat depressing that the voting on the site itself (and questions asked) do not tend to encourage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is there a procedure to recall US Senators?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/is-there-a-procedure-to-recall-us-senators)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why does Russia try to stop Ukraine from approaching to the EU](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/why-does-russia-try-to-stop-ukraine-from-approching-to-the-eu)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [If you are illegally searched, and the police find nothing, what can you do?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/if-you-are-illegally-searched-and-the-police-find-nothing-what-can-you-do)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are Prized Linked Savings Accounts legal in the United States?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/are-prized-linked-savings-accounts-legal-in-the-united-states)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [When will the US hit the debt ceiling again?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/when-will-the-us-hit-the-debt-ceiling-again)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is Israel's long-term plan in the West Bank?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/what-is-israels-long-term-plan-in-the-west-bank)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What remedy exists for unconstitutional changes to ObamaCare by the executive branch?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-remedy-exists-for-unconstitutional-changes-to-obamacare-by-the-executive-br)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the necessity of the FDIC in the US banking system?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/what-is-the-necessity-of-the-fdic-in-the-us-banking-system)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Was the Icelandic economic crisis of 2008 a product of lax government oversight or big government?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/was-the-icelandic-economic-crisis-of-2008-a-product-of-lax-government-oversight)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the nature of the "communist government" that West Bengal had for 34 years?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/what-is-the-nature-of-the-communist-government-that-west-bengal-had-for-34-yea)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Comment: I'm surprised that [this](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/what-is-israels-long-term-plan-in-the-west-bank) didn't have a better score.

Comment: Also, what could be improved about "Icelandic economic crisis" one?